# Const vs Final in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I was learning OOPS in C++ and I came across keywords `const` and `final`. Now I am having a doubt what is the difference between them.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `final` is not used to prevent a variable from being modified. In C++ it is used to prevent inheritance or overriding.

Comment: BTW, `final` is not a [keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) (contrary to `const`).

Comment: `final` is an *identifier with special meaning*.  You can use it as a variable name for example, so it's not quite a `keyword`. `final` is all do with overriding methods and inheriting from classes. It's not applied to variables in the same way as it is in, say, Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose this question needs an answer, given the other answers present.

You cannot apply `final` to variables in C++, so the question "which one is better" can only be answered with "`const`, because only this can compile".

---

`final` specifier was introduced to C++11 and can be applied:

1. to classes, in this case class cannot be used as a base class

```
class A final {};
class B: public A {}; //error
```

2. to `virtual` function, to prevent derived classes from overriding it

```
class A {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
class B: public A {
    void foo() final {}
};
class C: public B {
    void foo() {} //error
};
```

---

`const` keyword was in C++ since the very beginning and is used to

1. mark variables as non-modifiable. Non-member variables must be initialized where they are declared, member must be initialized in constructor initializer list. It's not like `final` in Java, you cannot assign to it once.

```
const std::vector<int> v;
v = std::vector<int>{}; //error
v.push_back(1); //error
```

2. to mark class member functions as usable with `const` objects. This also prevents you from modifying class members inside that function

```
class A {
    int n;
public:
    int getN() const {return n;}
    void setN(int n) {this->n = n;} //cannot be const, modifies a member
};

const A a;
a.getN(); //fine
a.setN(5); //error
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not what `final` is used for.  You might be confusing it with the use on other languages.

As you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final), `final` is not used when declaring variables at all.

```
const int val = foo();
```

This is how you define a variable that will not be changed, which is the situation you mention in your question.  `final` has nothing to do with it.  This might be similar to what `final` means in some other languages, since `foo()` is not known at compile time and the variable needs to be initialized and then not changed afterwards.  This is what `const` means in C++.

In C++, `final` is used to declare that a class will not be derived from, or a virtual function will not be further overridden.

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/174780) 
| 
[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/174780)

Comment: I've updated my answer.  This is the answer to the OP's question, so I hope it's not made invisible or deleted!

Comment: don't worry too much about early votes. The majority of votes is collected on the long run. And many users (in contrast to common belief) do not lightheartedly downvote, they might even come back to update the vote